# How to schedule hourly update of a variable for nodejs analytics?

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, analytics

I am building nodejs application that features analytics of hourly change in a particular column of the database and writes it to a table. 
e.g.

---

**column-Likes** => Stores like for a particular object

I want a Table like this

---

Time(timestamp) -------- Delta_Likes(or new likes received)

0hrs -------- 13

1hrs -------- 56

and so on ........

---

One simple answer I can think of is node-cron. But I do not know, how to make it work in production when many machines load balance the task.

Answer (score 0):

Plain js - setInterval to an hour spacing.

```
var duration = 60*60*1000; // 1 hour 
setInterval(function(){
  // your logging here
}, duration);
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, Brandon!! I had this in mind and didn't know it can work in production(I am a newbie). Is this a popularly followed practice; like I wonder how google analytics solves the problem.